# Visual Studio 2013 and Cmake?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, cmake, cmake-gui

I have been using 2010 on a project. The project was built using cmake, when cmake chose to use the compiler Visual Studio 2010. Now I intend to move the whole set up of the project to Visual Studio 2013.

So, today I installed Visual Studio 2013. But when I try to use cmake to build the project for visual studio 2013, in the compiler list of cmake I cannot see any compiler of Visual studio 2013, the latest are Visual Studio 2012, Visual Studio 2012 win64, Visual Studio 2012 ARM.

Is there no exclusive compiler for Visual Studio 2013? Does the same compiler work for both VS2012 and VS2013? If Visual Studio 2013 indeed has an exclusive compiler, why can't cmake find the that compiler?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try updating your CMake version.

The *Configue* dialog in `cmake-gui` for CMake 3.1 lists the respective entries as *Visual Studio 12 2013*:

[image]

In older CMake versions (older than 3.0) the entries omitted the year and showed only the version number, so the entry just reads *Visual Studio 12*.

If your CMake version is even older, there might not be support for Visual Studio 2013 at all. However, you should still be able to open project files generated for an older Visual Studio version. This might require an additional conversion step by Visual Studio, which might mess things up.

Upgrading CMake is definitely the preferred solution.